# Display the code credential on view during DeviceCodeCallback for Microsoft Graph API

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use device code credential method to call the Microsoft Graph API service. However, I have trouble getting the device code to be displayed at my View.

When I click the login button, it will trigger this controller :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MicrosoftLogin()
    {            

        var tenantId = "my-tenant-id";            
        var clientId = "my-client-id";
        var message = "";
        var options = new DeviceCodeCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            ClientId = clientId,
            TenantId = tenantId,
            DeviceCodeCallback = (code, cancellation) =>
            {
                message = code.Message;
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },
        };
        _deviceCodeCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(options);           
        ViewData["message"] = message;
        return View("DeviceCode");
    }
```

At the controller above, I am expecting to get the device code and pass back to my view. I understand that due to the asynchronouse nature of devic code callback, I would'nt get it. I've tried several approaches such as putting async and await on the device code callback,but it doesnt work.

The code.message is displayed on my .exe only when I trigger a call to this controller below :

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> MicrosoftCallback(string userEmail)
        {            
            var scopes = new[] { "Mail.Read", "User.Read" };
            graph = new GraphServiceClient(_deviceCodeCredential, scopes);
            var messages = await graph.Me.Messages
                .GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
                {
                    //some detail here...
                }
```

I am expecting the code to be displayed when I'm at DeviceCode View. Or is there anyway to improve the flow?

Comment: hi, I'm not very sure about it so I tried to send http request instead of using SDK, it worked for me anyway, pls take a try.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to display the device code in the view of an asp.net core web application, then you may try my code.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCodeAsync() {
            string[] scopes = new[] { "user.read" };
            string url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/";
            string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode";
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("client_id", "{client_id}");
            dict.Add("scope", "user.read openid profile");

            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, authority) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) }; ;
            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
            
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JObject obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);
                var deviceCode = obj["device_code"];
                ViewData["device_code"] = deviceCode;
            }
            return View();
        }
```

And don't forget to add corresponding platform.

[image]
[image]

my test result:

[image]